# how get user_timeline without oauth?

Tags: twitter

I used this code in Twitter API ver.1:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + username + '&count=' + count + '&callback=?', function(data){
```

However, Twitter API ver. 1.1 needs Oauth.

I need to access `user_timeline` without logging in.

Because the Twitter API ver.1 is retired, is there another way?

Comment: No, now you need to authenticate your request

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do it directly by javascript in a custom fashion.

The official word from Twitter is to use [Embedded Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines)

There is a [hack](https://plus.google.com/u/0/110804953626559077511/posts/j65ntqa5Qd3) to customise them, but I don't recommend it.

If you want a custom designed timeline, I suggest pulling the data via your own secure back end code.